# Converting a raw list to JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a raw list `sorteddict` in the form of :

```
["with", 1]
["witches", 1]
["witchcraft", 3]
```

and I want to generate more legible data by making it a JSON object that looks like:

```
"Frequencies": {
    "with": 1,
    "witches": 1,
    "witchcraft": 3,
    "will": 2
}
```

Unfortunately so far, I have only found a manual way to create data as shown above, and was wondering if there was a much more eloquent way of generating the data rather than my messy script. I got to the point where I needed to retrieve the last item in the list and ensure that there was no comma on the last line before I thought I should seek some advice. Here's what I had:

```
comma_count = 0
for i in sorteddict:
    comma_count += 1

with open("frequency.json", 'w') as f:
    json_head = "\"Frequencies\": {\n"
    f.write(json_head)
    while comma_count > 0:
        for s in sorteddict:
            f.write('\t\"' + s[0] + '\"' + ":" + str(s[1]) + ",\n")
            comma_count -= 1
    f.write("}")
```

I have used `json.JSONEncode.encode()` which I thought that was what I was looking for, but what ended up happening is `"Frequencies"` would be prepended to each `s[0]` item. Any ideas to clean the code?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a nested dict out of your current one, and use `json.dumps`. Not sure how sorteddict works, but:

```
json.dumps({"Frequencies": mySortedDict})
```

should work.

Additionally, you say that you want something json encoded, but your example is not valid json. So I will assume that you actually want legitimate json.

Here's some example code:

```
In [4]: import json

In [5]: # No idea what a sorteddict is, we assume it has the same interface as a normal dict. 

In [6]: the_dict = dict([
   ...:     ["with", 1],
   ...:     ["witches", 1],
   ...:     ["witchcraft", 3],
   ...: ])

In [7]: the_dict
Out[7]: {'witchcraft': 3, 'witches': 1, 'with': 1}

In [8]: json.dumps({"Frequencies": the_dict})
Out[8]: '{"Frequencies": {"with": 1, "witches": 1, "witchcraft": 3}}'
```

Comment: Almost right. ```from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

sorted_dict = SortedDict({...})```

Comment: @Alexander It's not a standard module and I don't want to speak to it specifically, but assuming it conforms to the dict interface, this example will work.

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered, so your example is misleading.

Comment: Ah I see, you're confused because I called my stand-in for OP's `sorted dict` "sorted_dict". I'll rename it to indicate that it's an example.

Comment: I would just add that the indent argument to json.dumps can be used to produce whitespace closer to the desired output (e.g., indent=4).  I find it makes the output more legible when it is printed.

Comment: You seem to have completely missed the question and made up your own question to suit your answer. You've created your own dictionary object and completely disregarded the two key variables, s[0] and s[1]. Quite simply `the dict = dict([[s[0], s[1]],])` would not work, if I handcrafted my own dictionary values it would obviously, but this is not the case in the context of this question

Answer (score 2):

I may not be understanding you correctly - but do you just want to turn a list of [word, frequency] lists into a dictionary?

```
frequency_lists = [
    ["with", 1],
    ["witches", 1],
    ["witchcraft", 3],
]
frequency_dict = dict(frequency_lists)
print(frequency_dict)  # {'with': 1, 'witches': 1, 'witchcraft': 3}
```

If you then want to write this to a file:

```
import json
with open('frequency.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(frequency_dict))
```